# AngularJS ng-show one condition with multiple elements

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click, ng-show

I have three divs with an ng-click with a "showMe" boolean. Their paragraphs have an ng-show that evaulates "showMe".

My question is, how can I use one condition to show the paragraph on the div I click? In other words, if I click the first div, I should only see "1", the "2" and "3" parapgraphs should stay hidden. ng-repeat is not an option for this exercise.

Here's a JSBin:

http://jsbin.com/kiwicipabago/1/edit

Thank you.

Comment: Write your own directive that implements the behavior you want, or, if you want it quick and dirty, use three separate boolean variables, not one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do like this :

```
<div ng-app="app">
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl">
  <div class="box" ng-click="showMe = 1">
    <p ng-show="showMe ==1">1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box" ng-click="showMe = 2">
    <p ng-show="showMe==2">2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box" ng-click="showMe = 3">
    <p ng-show="showMe ==3">3</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

All the  examples are in this [js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/evk4bbhk/), and a bit more elaborated.

Also, note that **jquery is not used**, I greatly **recommend not to use jquery in your AngularJs code**.
AngularJs include [jQuery lite](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element) accessible by the `angular.element` method. You should use it for any dom manipulation, if it doesn't provide you enough functionality, then think about creating a directive.

Look at this controller for more insight:

```js
app.controller("AppCtrl", ['$scope', function ($scope) {

    $scope.show_me = function (event) {
        var box = event.target.parentElement;
        var article = angular.element(box).find('article');
        var articles = angular.element(box.parentElement).find('article');
        // if already shown, hide it
        if (article.hasClass('show'))
            article.removeClass('show')
        else // elsif not shown, hide all and show it
        {
            articles.removeClass('show');
            article.addClass('show');
        }
    };

}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution that you can use, with the help of a little jQuery:

Add a function called `showMe` to your controller:

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);

  app.controller("AppCtrl", function($scope) {

  $scope.showMe = function(event) {
    $(event.target).find('p').toggle();
  };
});
```

And then in your HTML, change the following **from:**

```
...
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl">
  <div class="box" ng-click="showMe = !showMe">
    <p ng-show="showMe">1</p>
  </div>
</div>
...
```

**to:**

```
...
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl">
  <div class="box" ng-click="showMe($event)">
    <p>1</p>
  </div>
</div>
...
```

If you want to hide the `p` elements by default, you can just add a little CSS:

```
.box p {
  display: none;
}
```

JSBin: http://jsbin.com/fegevoyoda/2/

Comment: Please do not use jquery in your angularjs code. use the built-in [jquery lite](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element) instead, or create a directive.