# Accessing children using children in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am having two span, on click of one span tag, the p tag should show. Here is my HTML file:

```
<span class="span1" ng-click="show()">Span_1
<p class="p1" ng-show="var1">P_1</p>
</span>
<span class="span1" ng-click="show()">Span_2
<p class="p2" ng-show="var1">P_2</p>
</span>
```

and the corresponding jQuery is

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.var1 = false;
    $("span").click(function(){
        $(this).children().toggle();
    })
});
```

Is there any children() tag in Angularjs as well? The Plunker is http://plnkr.co/edit/UnyqbY6lLRqhAb8183Nf?p=preview

Comment: seems to be working fine https://jsfiddle.net/3jmqf9r9/1/

Comment: Ok thank but it is not working in plunker for me

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25369912/angularjs-ng-show-one-condition-with-multiple-elements) might help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please have a look of [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/nGAu8IhyRwyuH9glSCfZ?p=preview)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<span class="span1">Span_1
<p class="p1"  style="display:none;">P_1</p></span><br>
<span class="span1" >Span_2
<p class="p2" style="display:none;">P_2</p></span>

</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $("span").click(function(){
      console.log($(this).children())
      $(this).children().first().toggle();
    })
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank for the answer Gaurav but what is the use of this first() and also can I know why it is not working without this first() previously please.

Comment: Because without first it is returning an array of children, and array don't have toggle method and in first it is returning first element from children array which has togglw method

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use pure Angular here instead of using jQuery. I am not 100% sure what you are trying to achieve, but I guess you want to toggle p element when you click on specific span. If so, you can use such code:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.showChildren1 = false;    // show children of first span
    $scope.showChildren2 = false;    // show children of second span
    $scope.toggle1 = function(){
      $scope.showChildren1 = !$scope.showChildren1;  // toggle visibility
    }
    $scope.toggle2 = function(){
      $scope.showChildren2 = !$scope.showChildren2;   // toggle visibility
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <span class="span1" ng-click="toggle1()">Span_1</span><br>
    <p class="p1" ng-show="showChildren1">P_1</p>
    <span class="span1" ng-click="toggle2()">Span_2</span>
    <p class="p2" ng-show="showChildren2">P_2</p>
</div>
```

Here is the [updated sample](http://plnkr.co/edit/wmjGDYTu60Ja6AZgn3kn?p=preview)

Comment: I am having 32 span tags with inside p tag bro so on clicking on one span tag it should display it corresponding p tag so I was looking for that